# Laravel - how to send some value of a parameter from a blade view files to a controller?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

How to send value "{{$ item-> id}}" to some method in a controller?

e.g. show.blade.php - contains the value:

```
"{{$ item-> id}}"
```

MyController.php - contains the method:

```
public function results(Request $request){
    //and here I want to use the value {{$ item-> id}} 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make a form and post it , or have some hyperlink

```
<form  method="POST" action="/route_to_your_controller">
            {{ csrf_field() }} 
            <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{{$item->id}}" required>
</form>
```

Route

```
Route::post('/route_to_your_controller', 'yourController@results');
```

Controller

```
public function results(Request $request){
{
    $name = $request->input('item_id')     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your MyController use

```
public function results(Request $request, Item $item){
    //and here I want to use the value {{$ item-> id}}
 $item_id = $item->id;
}
```

You also have access to all the fields of item.